# How do I calculate top and left when resizing translated and rotated elements

Tags: html, trigonometry, css-transforms

I have a system where I'm able to drag and resize DIVs.
You can grab from the top and it will grow from the bottom. Grab from the bottom and it grows down from the top. Same with left, right, and corners.

This is all done with CSS width/height and translate(x,y) and works well.

Now I'm adding rotation and using something like this:

```
style="transform: translate(100px,100px) rotate(-30deg);width:100px;height:50px;"
```

Again, this is all good.

But when I change the width or height, the element shifts up/down or left/right.

See the following. The green div is the original, and the red one has the width expanded. You can see how it shifts.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
        body {
            position: relative;
        }

        .thing {
            position:absolute;
            border: solid 1px #0f0;
            transform: translate(100px, 100px) rotate(-30deg);
        }

        .thing2 {
            position:absolute;
            border: solid 1px #f00;
            transform: translate(100px, 100px) rotate(-30deg);
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="thing" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></div>
    <div class="thing2" style="width:150px;height:50px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know I need to recalculate the top/left based on trig, but haven't found the right calculations to make it work.

Also, I'd like to keep the rotation pivot around the center, so I can't just change the pivot point to one of the corners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll post an answer here in case anyone else hits this problem.

After locating this post: https://www.py4u.net/discuss/914662 the math is a little more clear.

It first grabs the location of the object along with the rotation, then for the new position it gets the location and then calculates the diff. Here's my functionalized version:

```
function calcNewPos(curr_x, curr_y, curr_w, curr_h, new_w, new_h, angle) {
    // convert angle to radians
    angle = angle * Math.PI / 180

    //initial position.
    let pos = {left: curr_x, top: curr_y};
    
    //Get position after rotation with original size
    let x = -curr_width/2;
    let y = curr_height/2;
    let new_x = y * Math.sin(angle) + x * Math.cos(angle);
    let new_y = y * Math.cos(angle) - x * Math.sin(angle);
    let p1 = {left: new_x - x, top: new_y - y};

    //Get position after rotation with new size
    x = -new_w/2;
    y = new_h/2;
    new_x = y * Math.sin(angle) + x * Math.cos(angle);
    new_y = y * Math.cos(angle) - x * Math.sin(angle);
    let p2 = {left: new_x - x, top: new_y - y};

    //Get the difference between the two positions
    let offset = {left: p2.left - p1.left, top: p2.top - p1.top};

    //Calculate the correction
    return {left: pos.left - offset.left, top: pos.top + offset.top};
}
```

I'm sure the math could be reduced in size, but this example lays it out there in an easy to understand way.

Answer (score 0):

here a solution with wrapper

```
<div class="thing-wrapper">
  <div class="thing left-top">expand right</div>
</div>

<div class="thing-wrapper">
  <div class="thing right-top">expand left</div>
</div>

<div class="thing-wrapper">
  <div class="thing left-bottom">expand top</div>
</div>

<div class="thing-wrapper">
  <div class="thing right-bottom">expand bottom</div>
</div>

.thing-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
}

.thing {
  border: solid 1px #0f0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(100px, 100px) rotate(-44deg);
  transition: 2s;
}

.thing.expand-left:hover,
.thing.expand-right:hover{
  width: 200px !important;
  height: 100px !important;
}

.thing.expand-top:hover,
.thing.expand-bottom:hover{
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 200px !important;
}

.expand-left {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.expand-right {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.expand-top {
  left:0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(300px, 300px) rotate(-44deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

.expand-bottom {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(300px, 300px) rotate(-44deg);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dt7phfk9/32/

positioning the thing in the wrapper works for expanding in only one direction.

Comment: Hm...actually it seems to have the same results. https://jsfiddle.net/Lufy4pwk/

Comment: You are right sorry.. the only way i could make it work was to set the transform origin to left top. but this is not what you want i gues

Comment: Thanks, your example works if resizing from the center. But my original goal is to resize from left to right. This illustrates is better using your example as a basis. https://jsfiddle.net/xnk9zujv/

Comment: So, what I'm really looking for is the math to determine the new x and y for translate(x,y) when resized to keep the position the same but stretched to the right (or left, or top, or bottom, depending on user input in my app).

Comment: so you mean you just want to expand one side at a time?

Comment: i updated the answer so you are able to expand in all directions

Comment: Thanks, your solution works by moving the transform-origin so sizing expands from it. But in my app I need to keep the origin at center because I'm allowing users to grab and rotate things. I could move the origin before the resize action, but that would result in the object moving, and expose the original problem of needing to compensate so it appears to remain fixed. I found the math here: https://www.py4u.net/discuss/914662

Comment: ok great! i hope your performance is still smooth while moving with calculation.